# What is the explanantion of plim X'X/n =Q?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Let X be a matrix where X may be any mixture of constants and random variables generated.

What is the meaning or intuitive explanation for the behaviour of the data in large samples where we have the following assumption:

$plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{X'X}{n}= Q$ where Q is a positive definite matrix?

Comment: Does the statement make sense for you if you put scalars there? E.g, does $x^2/n\to q$ in probability, where q is a real number give you any intuition?

Comment: Thank I got it! It means that by LLN E[$x^2$] is positive.

Comment: When $X$ is "a matrix" then $n$ is *fixed.* In what sense does $n$ go to infinity, then?

Comment: I'm not sure there is much to get from my comment, the notation I used does not make much sense, which I think is what @whuber is hinting at. Anyway, I wrote some thoughts in an answer instead.

Comment: For example, this assumption rules out a regressor with a growth trend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity and to get some intuition, suppose $ X=[x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_n]^T$ is an $n\times1$ vector of observations of some random variable $\textbf{x}$. Then you have $$\frac{1}{n}X'X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2.$$ It is clear that this is the sample analogue of $\mathbb{E}\textbf{x}^2$ so you can guess that the requirement has something to do with bounding the variance.

Since you tagged with econometrics, I guess you encounter this assumption when deriving some properties in relation to the OLS estimator. Then the assumption is, loosely speaking, just a way to make sure that as we collect more and more information, our sample estimate of the moment matrix consistently estimates the population moment matrix and that it is finite.

Now, you can try a more abstract case where $X$ has two columns of observations, perform the matrix multiplication and see what you get in each element of the resulting $2\times2$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks for making some sense of this.  BTW, I see that you have been here only two weeks and have been quite productive in contributing thoughtful answers.  Welcome to our site!